# How design an entity to entity relation in my SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a problem with design an entity to entity relation in my SQL database.
I have an entity that acts as a 'group'. And all groups has a relations to each other.

As an example:
GroupA and GroupB has a relation from groupA to groupB and vice versa with a bool.
It is like a 2D matrix:

Name | GroupA | Group B |

Group A | true | false

Group B | false | true |

The groups are dynamic, may there are more or less groups.
Now, how should I store this in my database?

Sorry for my bad english, and I hope someone understand what I mean :)

Comment: Have you ever heard of many-to-many relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two table:

```
GROUP
Name
...


GROUPTOGROUP
BaseGroupID
ConnectedToGroupID
True/False
```

So you can define any connection in the GroupToGroup.

Comment: Thanks! This was about I'm thinking - now I have confirmation that's the right way.

Comment: What will you do if new group is added?

Comment: I add a new entry in the 'GROUPTOGROUP' table.

Answer (score 0):

Table `Groups` with some `Id` column.
Table `GroupConnections` with `Group1Id` and `Group2Id` columns, `Group1Id <> Group2Id` and `unique Group1Id, Group2Id` constraints and foreign keys to `Groups`.

If there is a connection (`true` in your matrix), there should be a record in `GroupConnections`. If there isn't, there shouldn't.